# Displaying developer exceptions in multiple environments in ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I'm able to right-click --> Publish a .NET core Razor application to a remote IIS server with different publishing profiles, but I can only see developer exceptions when the EnvironmentName is set to Development in the publishing profile...

```
<PropertyGroup>    
    <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

Otherwise I see:

```
Development Mode
Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

Is there a way to change the environment name to something custom and still see developer exceptions? I've found mention of `env.IsDevelopment()` here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environments but I'm not sure if I can use this, or in what file. I'd like to be able to use multiple appSettings files like `appsettings.Azure_dev.json` and still see developer exceptions. Thank you!

Edit... what I ended up doing:

I made a list of valid development environments for my project in `appsettings.json`

```
  "Deploy_Settings": {
    "Dev_Environments": "Development;Azure_Dev"
  },
```

and checked the environment name against them in the `Program.cs` file

```
List<string> listDevEnvs = new List<string>(configuration.GetSection("Deploy_Settings")["Dev_Environments"].Split(new char[] { ';' }));
string CurrEnvName = app.Environment.EnvironmentName;

// This is to show Developer Exception errors in deployments with Environment names other than 'Development'
if (listDevEnvs.Contains(CurrEnvName))
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the extension method [`DeveloperExceptionPageExtensions.UseDeveloperExceptionPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.developerexceptionpageextensions.usedeveloperexceptionpage?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You can enable this whenever you want.